# How to put an h1 on the same line and in the middle of a nav ul

Tags: html, css

I am making a `nav` bar for my site.  In I want the `nav` bar to have horizontally centered `li` items, except I wan the middle item to be an `h1` that is preferably not part of the list. (This is to keep `nav` items specific to navigation, not the title of the page.

Right now my HTML looks like this (I am using icon-fonts btw):

```
<nav class="nav">
    <h1>Page title</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><span data-icon="&#xE603;"></span><h2>HOME</h2></li>
        <li><span data-icon="&#xE603;"></span><h2>ABOUT</h2></li>
        <li><span data-icon="&#xE603;"></span><h2>CONTACT</h2></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And my css is this:

```
nav {
    background: gray;
    text-align: center;
}
nav li:first-child {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

nav li {
    float: right
}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

No matter what I try I can not get the h1 on the same line.  Note that I *do not* want to just insert a `p` element as the second item on the list. Any help would be great.

Comment: Absolute positioning or two lists with `h1` in the middle with defined `width`.

Comment: Headings display as block elements.  If you wish to use it inline, you will have to float it or change its display.

Comment: I tried floating it and the `margin: 0 auto` would not center it. Two lists in one nav? Isn't that bad syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding this will help:

```
nav { position: relative; }
nav h1 { position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%; }
```